# Specify range of nodes - Xpath/Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to figure out to specify a range of nodes. I have seen examples using "and" within two xpath equations but I cannot get it to work, either it returns nothihng or gives errors.

For example I have this current statement

```
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]//tbody//tr[3]//table[1]");
foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes(".//tr//td").Skip(2))
{
     string cleanedHtml = cleaner(cell.InnerText.Trim());
     QuoteItems.Add(cleanedHtml);
}
```

Now, if I wanted to get that Htmlnode, but specify everything from the first `tr` to the 6th `tr`, how would I do this?

i.e. 
I want everything from

```
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]//tbody/tr[3]//table[1]");
```

to

```
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]//tbody/tr[6]//table[1]");
```

As mentioned I have tried this, but I just get a first chance exception.

```
"//table[2]//tbody/tr[position() >= 3 and position() <=6]//table[1]"
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put an `and` in the middle of that expression:

```
"//table[2]//tbody/tr[position() >= 3 and position() <=6]//table[1]"
```

Comment: oh duh haha. I do have this, but it only gives me the first element in this situation, so only `tr[3]` appears and not `tr[6]`.

Comment: @Austin, if you're lamenting that `SelectSingleNode` is only selecting a single node, use `SelectNodes` instead.

Comment: @kjhughes How do I get a single element of multiple nodes? If I do two foreach's (wrap a foreach doing the expression above) then I get the result multiple times. Is there a way to make like a HtmlNode be multiple nodes, as a HtmlNode cannot = a collection of nodes (.SelectNodes).

Comment: AH wait nvm, I didn't update my value.SelectNodes for the inner loop. Ty Kj!

Comment: You're welcome.  Let's give Lars his due and call this a wrap.